# SWIFT URLResponse no output // Google Maps PI

Tags: json, swift, xcode, url, google-maps-api-3

I build an little task in SWIFT-XCode where I am trying to fetch and print some JSON Data, but the console doesn´t show me any error´s or result. Maybe someone can help me with the problem?. Here´s my code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(lat),\(long)&destination=\(lat+auflong),\(long+auflat)&key=**************")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                // Convert the data to JSON
                let jsonSerialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]

                if let json = jsonSerialized, let url = json["url"], let explanation = json["explanation"] {
                    print(url)
                    print(explanation)
                }
            }  catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug-step through the code, you see the result in the debug area: watch area.

In my test (using incorrect co-ordinates), when I put a breakpoint at the line starting `let jsonSerialized = '..., return 3 dictionary keys:

status

error_message

routes

But you were expecting **url** and **explantion**...

If you change the inner like:

```
            let jsonSerialized = ...

            if let json = jsonSerialized
            {
                print(json)
                if let url = json["url"], let explanation = json["explanation"] {
                    print(url)
                    print(explanation)
                }
            }
        }  catch ...
```

you'll be able to print the returned **json**.  (Replaced some code with ... for easy reading.)

My output:
    ["status": REQUEST_DENIED, "error_message": The provided API key is invalid., "routes": <__NSArray0 0x600000003910>(

)
    ]